# IdentityServer3 and persistent cookies

Tags: identityserver3

Have a question about IdentityServer3 login with "remember me" option checked.
It creates persistent cookie with 30 day expiration as default and it works just fine but only for 24h.

On next day IS asking for relogin (automatically redirects on login) even with valid security cookies seen in cookie storage:

[image]

IS is hosted on IIS, can the situation be related to application pool recycling?
What can be done to prevent this?

**UPDATE 13.8 15:00**: Ok, as machine key is configured in app config (or machine.config) cookie decryption is working just fine even after pool recycle.